# Extract values from slicer in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, slicers

Is there a way to extract value from a date slicer.

Say suppose in my date slicer I have selected 26-11-2019 and 29-12-2019.

I need to extract both the dates and use these value in two diff measures.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Get the min and max value of your dates table, which is filtered by this slicer.

Comment: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-the-selectedvalue-function-in-dax/

Answer (score 0):

For the first measure, try this

```
Slicer Selected Value = Var selectedValue = MIN('Calendar'[Date])
Return
CALCULATE(SUM('Calendar'[Date]),'Calendar'[Date] = selectedValue)
```

For the second measure, try this

```
Slicer Selected Value = Var selectedValue = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
Return
CALCULATE(SUM('Calendar'[Date]),'Calendar'[Date] = selectedValue)
```

> for more details, Please check **[power bi measure based on slicer](https://debug.to/890/power-bi-measure-based-on-slicer?)**